# Unable to decrypt/decode key

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, amazon-ec2, twitter

It appears that my consumer secret key for Twitter API 1.1 is not being decrypted in my CodeIgniter controller on my Amazon EC2 instance [(slightly similar to this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026242/codeigniter-cannot-decode-the-encrypted-password) because

- I got an `unable to authenticate you` error while troubleshooting
- and my `print_r($settings)` statement (see below) displays unreadeable characters for the consumer secret in the browser inspite of the fact that I decrypted it with this line `'consumer_secret' => $this->encrypt->decode($this->config->item('consumer_secret')`.

**my_controller.php**

```
$settings = array(
            'oauth_access_token' => $this->config->item('oauth_access_token'),
            'oauth_access_token_secret' => $this->config->item('oauth_access_token_secret'),
            'consumer_key' => $this->config->item('consumer_key'),
            'consumer_secret' => $this->encrypt->decode($this->config->item('consumer_secret'))
        );  
        print_r($settings);
```

Note: I saved the **encrypted** consumer secret key in CodeIgniter's configuration directory and also set my encryption key in config.php. Interestingly, it works fine in WAMP but not in Amazon EC2.

How do I resolve this problem? Should I just save the unencrypted consumer secret key in the configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter uses some standard encryption libraries and falls back if they aren't available. I don't think `mcrypt` is available on the default Amazon Linux AMI. You can

a) use the fallback; just re-encrypt the consumer_secret on ec2 and put it in the config

b) install mcrypt

```
$ sudo yum install php-mcrypt
$ sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply stormdrain. Re-encrypt? Oh, because what I actually did was just save the encrypted string in the config file. I never explicitly encrypted it.

Comment: How did it get encrypted? I was under the impression you encrypted it via `$this->encrypt->encode('consumer_secret_string123123123');` and stored the result in the config. If that was the case, when you created the encrypted consumer secret on WAMP it was likely using mcrypt which isn't available on default ec2 micro which means it won't decrypt correctly.

Comment: Stormdrain, you are brilliant! I installed mcrypt and restarted httpd and I see my the key now thanks so much again! How did I encrypt the key? I just did a echo encrypt->encode('my_key'); and copied the code from my browser, I know, very noob lol but I'm learning slowly but surly. Thanks so much again!

Comment: Yeah that's an effective way -- just echo it out and copy it down. The problem is the result will differ depending on how the encryption happens (crypto is very, very, very complicated). [mcrypt](http://mcrypt.sourceforge.net/) is an encryption library which needs to be installed on the system you are using. WAMP comes with it, but ec2 micro does not. So you encrypted the string locally with mcrypt, but when you got on ec2, mcrypt wasn't there so CI fell back to another encryption method to decrypt the string which isn't compatible, leaving you with a string of gibberish :)

Comment: To clarify, on EC2 it depends which AMI you are using as to whether its installed by default.

Comment: @datasage good point, thanks. We're referring to the Amazon Linux AMI.

Comment: stormdrain, my twitter app is working completely now on EC2. I just have to pretty it up a bit with some CSS, and refactor the code and learn how to write unit test, but all in all, I am really happy now!

Comment: Good to hear Anthony. Now comes the fun part (actually working with code) :) Enjoy!

Comment: Yes, I used Amazon Linux AMI micro instance. Thanks again for mentioning the "fall backs" - that really hit home for me, thanks.