# Php 5.3 mcrypt not working on CentOS 6.3 32-bit

Tags: php, codeigniter, mcrypt, centos6

My CodeIgniter application works fine on Amazon EC2 64-bit AMI micro instance thanks to @stormdrain who [recommended I install mcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799539/unable-to-decrypt-decode-key) to resolve a non-functioning `$this->encrypt->decode(...);` which was not decrypting my key. Its working now. However, when I copied the same application (using scp) to my local 32-bit machine running CentOS 6.3, I'm getting the same problem (`$this->encrypt->decode(...);` is not decrypting my key).

So I installed mcrypt `sudo yum install php-mcrypt`. However, `which php-mcrypt` and `which mcrypt` was not found. `whereis php-mcrypt` and `whereis mcrypt` turned up nothing. `sudo yum php-mcrypt` resulted in `Package php-mcrypt-5.3.3-1.el6.rf.i686 already installed and latest version. Nothing to do`. `sudo yum libmcrypt` revealed `Package libmcrypt-2.5.7-1.2.el6.rf.i686 already installed and latest version. Nothing to do`. `php --version` showed PHP 5.3.3. I searched for mcrypt in the php.ini file but found nothing. `echo phpinfo` only found one entry besides `Additional .ini files parsed: /mcrypt.ini`. However, I can't locate this file. The same Encryption Key is already set in CodeIgniter's config.php.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if you couldn't find it in the ini file, why not add it?

Comment: +1 @JohnVanDeWeghe . I thought I would find a line like this commented out: `;extension=php_mcrypt.dll` however, I guess this is only for Windows. So I searched for `mcrypt` alone but found nothing. What exactly should I add to the php.ini file?

Comment: find another extension in the file and copy the syntax, I can't remember it off hand sorry.

Comment: Are you using windows or centos? If centos did you check in /etc/php.d/*?

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe That is the interesting thing! I searched for extension and ;extension but  I did not find a line like `;extension-php_mcrypt.....`. Let me look again, this time I'll try to look through the entire file

Comment: +1 @R.S I'm using CentOS 6.3. My 32-bit computer is dual booted with CentOS 6.3 and Windows XP.

Comment: @R.S I'm using CentOS 6.3 with php 5.3.

Comment: After installing php_mcrypt by doing 'yum install ...' did you restart apache by doing 'service httpd restart'?

Comment: Yes I did, `sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: Try `sudo ll /etc/php.d/`, does it list mcrypt.ini?

Comment: I assumed that when my `which foo` and `whereis foo` returned nothing, I thought something went wrong with my installation of mcrypt.

Comment: I got a `sudo ll: Command not found` and `sudo 11: Command not found` for both `sudo ll /etc/php.d/` and `sudo 11 /etc/php.d/`

Comment: +1 @R.S yes I found it `; Enable mcrypt extension module` and in the next line: `extension=module.so`

Comment: Try `sudo ls /etc/php.d/`

Comment: +1 @R.S yes, `sudo ls /etc/php.d/` showed mcrypt.ini. Inside it was this: `; Enable mcrypt extension module` and in the next line: `extension=module.so`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seem to be a issue in the 32bit version of mcrypt when using `yum install php-mcrypt` to install. Take a look @ [Installing php-mcrypt on centos 6.4 (32 bytes) causes problem](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=42375), the mcrypt.ini file has the wrong entry

You need to edit `/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini` and change

```
extension=module.so
```

To

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Then save and restart apache.

Comment: +1 Thank you soo much @R.S It worked. My key was decrypted! Thanks again.